# Remove last element of one array and add it to the beggining of a second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP:

```
$first_array = array();
$second_array = array();
```

Each array has different values
ex:

```
// first array
array (size=2)
  0 => int 100
  1 => int 200

// second array
array (size=2)
  0 => int 300
  1 => int 400
```

I want to move the last element of first array (which is dynamic size) to the first element of second array. So result would be:

```
// first array
array (size=1)
  0 => int 100

// second array
array (size=3)
  0 => int 200
  1 => int 300
  2 => int 400
```

any ideas how to do this?

Comment: BTW I had an answer for your deleted question.  Ask it again but add some attempt and it shouldn't be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = [100, 200];
$array2 = [300, 400];

array_unshift($array2,  array_pop($array1));

print_r($array1); # prints 100
print_r($array2);  # prints 200, 300, 400
```

Comment: PHP 7.4+ alternative: `$array2 = [array_pop($array1), ...$array2];`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_pop()` to pop off the last element. Use `array_unshift()` to push an element at the beginning of an array. I’m not sure what the indexes are, but `array_values()` can reset the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```php
// add last element of $first_array on top of $second_array
array_unshift( $second_array, end( $first_array ) );
// delete last element of $first_array
unset( $first_array[ key( $first_array ) ] );
```